# Gridview not updating on PostBackTrigger

Tags: asp.net, gridview, c#-3.0, updatepanel

Guys i have a form and a data gridview in the same page. I bind my data gridview to a SQL and use my form to submit records to the database. My form and my gridview are on thesame page. I want to force my grid to reload and update its records automatically ,whenever a new record is inserted. In order i want to see my new record displayed in the gridview. I use the update panel triggers function as below

```
 </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>  
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEmailSave" />

    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My problem is , when ever i click the 'btnEmailSave', my records get inserted and the page reload as expected. However the gridview records don't change.It rather remain the same.

I bind my gridview as follows in the pageload method.

```
if (!(IsPostBack))
            {
                bindEmail();
                bindDrClient();
            }
```

Please i am not sure why it isn't updating. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a method for binding the grid.??

Comment: Yah the `bindEmail()` method above binds the grid.

Comment: You need to bind the grid on btnEmailSave click after the record inserted to db.

Comment: call this method again once the data is inserted in the DB.

Comment: Your Soulution did work guys. Thank you all. However i am not sure how to accept an answer from a comment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys. My problem is solved by Sain above. I just need to call the method

```
 bindEmail()
```

As soon as the records are inserted. It works now and fine.